# How do you say “mass extinction” in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

We’re talking about the climate crisis and the fact that many species die out, go extinct, every hour of every day. So the translation needs to be pretty dramatic as well, but also clear.

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives:
Amasa elradikiĝo - one of the meanings of elradikiĝo in PIV covers this “extinction” meaning. I don’t think the meanings is clear without consulting a dictionary, because you could also move people away from their roots/with their roots and they don’t die.
Amasa estingo- “Estingo” as in shut down, malfunkcii

Amasa formorto - simple and clear that it’s about death. Not clear that it is the disappearance of a lot of species forever with no return. Could just be mass death.

Amasa ekstermo- ekstermo means that it is intentional, which can be a meaning you want, but not in this case

Amasa forpereo- also a good alternative, but only if he meaning of “perei” is immediately clear
I’m not satisfied with any of these alternatives. More ideas?

Comment: _amasa forpereo de specioj_ estas, laŭ mi, tute taŭga. La signifo de _perei_ estas sufiĉe klara. Oni povas morti pro simpla maljuneco, sed _perei_ ja montras ke tio estis neatendita/akcidenta afero. Cetere, la difino PIVa de forperei estas "malaperi pereinte". Trafa ja.

Comment: What does PIV means?

Comment: "PIV" estas akronimo por Plena Ilustrita Vortaro de Esperanto. (vortaro.net)

Answer (score 3):

Mi opinias ke ***amasa estingiĝo*** estas taŭga eblo. Laŭ ReVo *estingiĝo* signifas interalie *iom post iom malaperi*.

Ekzemplo el Tekstaro:

> Ni konstatas amasan estingiĝon de plantaj kaj bestaj specioj, unu el
>   la plej brutalaj kaj rapidaj estingiĝoj iam ajn okazintaj en la Tero.